# Usar valor de otro form para consulta sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Intento obtener el valor de otro form(txtusuario) para hacer una consulta y mostrar en labels pero al correr el programa no me ejecuta nada, no se si estoy haciendo algo mal o llamando algo mal.

Con esto mando el dato a form2

```
String Usuario = txtUsuario.Text;
new Menu(Usuario).Show();
```

Y cuando trato de ejecutarla es con este codigo

```
 public Menu(string usuario)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            hideSubMenu();
            Vuser(usuario);
        }



        private void Vuser(string usuario)
        {

            string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["produccion"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                conexion.Open();
                //evitamos inyeccion
                System.Text.StringBuilder sel = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select a.Login,a.Supervisor, b.Nombre from Usuarios a INNER JOIN CatalogoSucursales b ON a.CodigoSucursal " +
                    "= b.CodigoSucursal WHERE A.Login='@usuario'", conexion))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = usuario;
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        lblUsuario1.Text = (string)reader["Login"].ToString();
                        lblSucursal.Text = (string)reader["Nombre"].ToString();
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en como le pasas los parámetros.
Reproduzco tú ejemplo completo.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Usuarios
(CodigoSucursal INT, 
 Login          VARCHAR(50), 
 Supervisor     VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.CatalogoSucursales
(CodigoSucursal INT, 
 Nombre         VARCHAR(100)
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Usuarios (CodigoSucursal, Login, Supervisor)
values
(1,'Juan'  ,'Ana'),
(2,'Carlos','Bea');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.CatalogoSucursales (CodigoSucursal, Nombre)
values
(1,'Central'),
(2,'Periférica');
GO

Select a.Login,a.Supervisor, b.Nombre from Usuarios a INNER JOIN    CatalogoSucursales b ON a.CodigoSucursal = b.CodigoSucursal WHERE A.Login='Juan'
```

Por tanto en Sql si llamo a Juan, me devuelve una fila.

En c# me he creado un form.

```
    public Form10()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String Usuario = txtUsuario.Text;
        new Menu(Usuario).Show();
    }
```

Esta es la pinta:

[image: Form1]

Luego me he creado un form Menu, al cuál le he cambiado muy poco. Si observas, he sacado la sql a una variable, (cuestión de gustos), he quitado el stringBuilder que no usas, he comentado el hideSubMenu porque no interviene en el código. Te he envuelto la conexión en un try catch, y aquí el problema de tu query, he quitado los apóstrofes del parámetro.

```
        public Menu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public Menu(string usuario)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       // hideSubMenu();
        Vuser(usuario);
    }

    private void Vuser(string usuario)
    {

        try
        {
            string con = @"Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=FOROS;Server=ESQUINERO";

            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                conexion.Open();
                //evitamos inyeccion
                string sql = "Select a.Login,a.Supervisor, b.Nombre from Usuarios a INNER JOIN CatalogoSucursales b ON a.CodigoSucursal " +
                    "= b.CodigoSucursal WHERE a.[Login] = @usuario;";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = usuario;
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        lblUsuario1.Text = reader["Login"].ToString();
                        lblSucursal.Text = reader["Nombre"].ToString();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Cuando ejecuto la query tal cual estaba antes el aplicativo, envia a Sql lo siguiente:

```
exec sp_executesql N'Select a.Login,a.Supervisor, b.Nombre from Usuarios a INNER JOIN CatalogoSucursales b ON a.CodigoSucursal = b.CodigoSucursal WHERE a.[Login] = ''@usuario'';',N'@usuario varchar(50)',@usuario='Juan'
```

Pero si le quitas los apóstrofes a la query, el envía esto.

```
exec sp_executesql N'Select a.Login,a.Supervisor, b.Nombre from Usuarios a INNER JOIN CatalogoSucursales b ON a.CodigoSucursal = b.CodigoSucursal WHERE a.[Login] = @usuario;',N'@usuario varchar(50)',@usuario='Juan'
```

Como en los parámetros ya le dices que es un varchar, el ya sabe que va entre apóstrofes, por tanto con esta sentencia, la ejecución es correcta.

[image: Resultado Final]

Comment: Viejo, no se como agradecerte me lo has hecho entender tan claro.... te agradezco mucho!!, ahora solo tengo que ver si el resultado de supervisor es 1 que este ponga en el label "Supervisor", pero muchisimas gracias!

Comment: De nada. En el ejemplo, no mencionabas nada del supervisor es 1. Aunque me supongo que será alguna condición de la query.